# Objective-C / iOS -- Class design that triggers differently depending on external data

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

This is based on a tangential alternative that arose from my other post on dispatch tables.

In objective-c object-oriented design, suppose I am designing a class that requires external data to execute. The class has a number of variations, and each variation executes differently, at different times, based on different external data. What is the best way to execute/implement this design?

As a concrete example, suppose the class is to represent a medical condition. There are 100-200 different medical conditions, each of which reacts to different stimuli, and each of which does different things once triggered.

The primary difficulty with which I need help is how to pass in the data necessary for each variation to execute once triggered -- data that cannot be encapsulated, and data that cannot be simply used as argument to input into an overridden function by the nature of being different for every variation of medical condition.

For instance, when the sunburn condition triggers, it needs data for the weather passed in, to determine the severity. When insomnia triggers, it needs a recent history of other medication taken. Indigestion needs weight of food consumed. The trigger points also differ, of course, but I've enumerated that and stored it as a enum value in my superclass. The question is how to handle data: do I subclass for every possible input that any subclass could possibly need? Or use a design pattern like Visitor?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Here's an example situation that I hope can make my question more concrete:

A bunch of patients are admitted into a room, and each one has a different MedicalCondition (in my current code, I do not subclass MedicalCondition, I only call them different NSString names). It's a property of Patient. Then, through the flow of the program, various MedicalTests are conducted on each Patient.  MedicalTest has data like "int power" and "BOOL putsPatientToSleep" and "float chanceOfCausingFainting" and also vary greatly from MedicalTest to MedicalTest.  The room itself also has qualities like isSunny, isDark, fullOfContagiousPatients, etc. that become data that I will need once a MedicalCondition flares up.

Now, through the battery of tests, suppose one happens that is one of the triggers for the tested Patient's MedicalCondition. Let's say it's called @"sunburn"  The MedicalTest had a quality that causes the tested Patient's MedicalCondition to activate. My problem, in essence, is, where and how do I write the activation code for ExecuteWhenThisConditionFlaresUp(...input that varies from MedicalCondition to MedicalCondition...)?  When the sunburn Patient has his MedicalCondition fire, how do I vary that response from the response of a chills Patient, for example? I can write the function fairly simply given the input data, but the problem is that the input data (i.e. function signature) will differ from Condition to Condition, and I also have 100s of MedicalConditions that do different things, so I'm not sure if it's the right thing to subclass MedicalCondition just to have different behavior on flare-up. Is there any way to index or store a functor in objective-c? Maybe write 100 different functions, all with different signatures but given access to a general input NSArray, and then store the appropriate functor with the appropriate NSString? (keeping only ONE MedicalCondition class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I can see to do this is to have each medical condition keep an array of required inputs and stimuli to check,

```
@interface Condition <NSObject>
   @property (retain) NSArray* stimuliForCondition
   @property (retain) NSArray* requiredInputsOnceTriggered

   -(BOOL) conditionIsActivated: (NSDictionary*) stimuli;
   -(void) applyConditionWithInputs: (NSDictionary*) inputs;
@end
```

and the object which manages the execution of each condition can then read the arrays, which might consist of strings corresponding to keys in a dictionary in your "world" object which contains data like medication history and weight of food, which I'll call "WorldData."

```
@interface WorldData
{

 //things are stored as @"Other Medication Taken" -> some value of medication taken
  NSDictionary* allData;
}
@end 

@implemetation PatientData

-(void) checkForCondition 
{
   for (NSObject<Condition>* condition in allConditions) {

       NSMutableDictionary* stimuliDict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       for (NSString* keyForStimuli in condition.stimuliForCondition) {

            stimuliDict[keyForStimuli] = allData[keyForStimuli];
       }

       if([condition conditionIsActivated: stimuliDict]) {

             NSMutableDictionary* inputDict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
             for(NSString* keyForInput in condition.inputs) {

                  inputDict[keyForInput] = allData[keyForInput];
             }

             [condition applyConditionWithInputs: inputDict];
       }
   }
}
```

This way you can pass arbitrary data into the two methods in the Condition protocol, and implement the logic as each condition demands.

EDIT: To your question in the comments, I think it depends on the sophistication of the logic you need in those methods. Here are two scenarios:

1. You just need to check if a certain set of numbers is in a certain range, or other extremely generic checks, and the application of the effects of a condition is similarly generic. Here's an example of this case, where the test for if a stimulus is met is merely if it exceeds a certain threshold, and we'll load our conditions in from .plist files which consist of a dictionary mapping thresholds to stimuli names.

   @interface Condition ()

   ```
   //maps the thresholds for activation to each stimuli
   NSDictionary* stimuliActivations;
   @end
   @implementation Condition

   -(id) initWithConditionName: (NSString*) conditionName
   {

   if (self = [super init]) {

       //load in our stimuli from a plist
       NSData* conditionFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: conditionName ofType: @"plist" inDirectory: nil]];
   _stimuliForCondition = [[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData: conditionFileData mutabilityOption: NSPropertyListImmutable format: NULL errorDescription: nil] retain];

       _requiredInputsOnceTriggered = //the same thing for the appropriate plist file

       stimuliActivations = // same thing
   }

        return self;
   }

   -(BOOL) conditionIsActivated: (NSDictionary*) stimuli
   {

       NSUInteger numActivatedStimuli = 0;
       for (NSString* currStimuli in [stimuli allkeys]) {
           if (stimuli[currStimuli] > stimuliActivations[currStimuli]) {

              numActivatedStimuli++;
           }
       }

       return (numActivatedStimuli == _stimuliForCondition.length ? YES : NO);
    }

   @end
   ```
2. Case two: Stimuli and/or the application of conditions is complex and requires custom logic for each condition which cannot be broken into simple generic implementations like "if value is greater than," "value is between," "value is equal to". In this case, you should make a "Condition" protocol (so you don't have to have some generic class to inherit from that you never want instantiated) which is implemented by other objects, and implement the logic separately for each condition, with the interface ensuring that you only need one method signature for each. That way you don't have a bloated Condition.m.

I think that using selectors is overkill for this. Selectors and invocations are good when you need to determine the method to send at runtime, but you have many options here that are simpler and map better to reality (diseases are objects, not functions) than that.

Comment: Nice answer! Concrete code from those high-level requirements. I'm impressed.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben Pious!  NSArray for keys is awesome, but could NSArray even store heterogeneous data (different data classes subclassed from NSObject)? If so, that would definitely work as a way to get data into generic classes.

Comment: @Cindeselia - You can put any kind of object into an NSArray. You might also want to look at creating your own look-up classes that uses an array internally.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! @Cinideselia -- I'm a bit confused by the wording -- if your question is "can I put things that aren't NSObjects into an NSArray," then yes -- my answer proposes putting in NSStrings, which fit your description of "data class subclassed from NSObject." If your question is "can I put something other than a string in my stimulus or input arrays, and then use it as a key in my dictionaries, then there is no technical reason why not -- whatever makes the most sense in your program is the right answer.

Comment: Sorry for my bad wording. I need to try it out myself (in the doc it just says (id)s are stored), but I meant putting different inputs in the same NSArray. Like array[0] is a NSWeatherState (subclass of NSObject), array[1] is an NSMove (subclass of NSObject), ... and maybe even use an NSString somewhere down the array. That way, all the activate functions would take an NSArray, some shorter than others, and how they interpret it (which contents the activate function accesses) varies from MedicalCondition to MedicalCondition.

Comment: @Ben Pious -- Sorry, but one more all-important question regarding the Condition model: How would you load in the 100+ Conditions? I like your interface -- it has everything necessary, and it is simple. Thank you! But I'm conflicted as to whether I should subclass Condition 100+ times just to override applyConditionWithInputs, or just write 100 functions in Condition.m that I pass in as selectors (like a functor model)? [condition applyConditionWithInputs:inputDict] is awesome. Not sure how I would do selectors, but someone mentioned it as a way to keep function execution generic.

Comment: Like, I can definitely "load in" the data about which triggers and which inputs are necessary from a text file, but, somewhere, the applyConditionsWithInput implementation has to be hard-coded, either in a subclass .m file for each differently executing Condition, or as a function/method meant to be passed via selector to the generic Condition, indexed by a NSString name. Once I figure that out, I'm good to go!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a perfect example of the *[composition vs inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)* problem.

If you try to use inheritance for this, you'll run into the a problem. Imaging you have a class ***Employee*** with sub-classes ***Technician*** and ***Manager***. Now imaging you have a class ***Customer***, with various sub-classes. What happens when you have a ***Customer*** that is also a ***Manager***? In Objective-C there is a single inheritance chain (fortunately), so this would be difficult to model with inheritance.

The solution to this problem is to use composition instead. This is deceptively simple - it simply means you create a container class and add traits (ie protocols or concrete collaborators to it).

**It would go something like this:**

- Create the top-level ***MedicalCondition*** class.
- Into this medical conditions can go other objects. For example ***ChronicDisease***, ***AcuteDisease***, ***Symptoms***, ***VitalSigns***, etc.
- Look commonalities and try to extract Abstract base classes or interfaces to which you can add to the medical condition.

It sounds as though you could add a collection of ***Trigger*** objects to a ***MedicalCondition***. This might be a Protocol or an abstract base class.

You might be interested in exploring *[domain-driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)*.

As far as other specific patterns that might be relevant, its difficult to say given the high-level requirements that you described in your question. I would say try to focus on the requirements themselves and the process of modeling them, rather than looking for a pattern to apply early on. As you continue to model the appropriate pattern will shout out out you.

**Update: (based on comments discussion)**

Consider using the observer pattern. In this you can have triggers. Any time you call the setActivated method on a trigger, any disease observing this can perform an action. The Apple framework for this is key-value observing (KVO). . there's also an open-source framework called ReactiveCocoa, that you might find interesting.

Comment: Thanks. It is a turn based game in which two players that don't know about their opponent's medical conditions attack each other. At certain stimuli of attack (such as changing weather to sunny), certain conditions flare up and do something such as debilitating the person with the condition, or exacerbating damage from fire attacks, etc. The trigger point just tells me when to check for whether to activate in the flow of a game turn, but it's the actual varied effects of conditions that is complicated, since they depend on more than just who has the condition, but also other

Comment: objects (in OoP sense), like WorldState, attackReceivedFromFoe, previousAction, nextAction, etc.  I will think more and reply, add code etc

Comment: @Cindeselia - Sounds great. Will it be an AppStore published game? If so leave a comment when it's ready - I'd love to play.

Comment: I'm not too well-versed in OOP, but I had this misconception that one of the other obstacles to inheritance besides your Manager-Customer example is creating too many subclasses (like, 100s of them) when unnecessary. Composition is a good way, as you kindly pointed out, to make a MedicalCondition able to handle as many different cases as possible, without creating 100 subclasses. The activation part still troubles me, though. Even with composition, somewhere the unique DoThisWhenIFlareUp(..inputs..) needs to be implemented, and I'm not sure where: subclass override? Functor?

Comment: @Cindeselia Can you just have the disease conform to a Flarable protocol? Each condition could implmeent onFlareUp in its own way. . . perhaps you could also have subscribers to the flare-up event? So on flare-up you could notify x number of observers. .

Comment: Conceptually, the only way I've learned besides subclassing to achieve variable behavior from a generic function call is to pass a function pointer, or activate a functor. Not sure how either of those would work for me in obj-c. MedicalCondition behavior is so unique from condition to condition that I can't just write one function, unless I use a switch statement with 100 branches (impractical). So the question becomes, where do I write the functions, and how do I access the right one when a condition is triggered? (index a NSDictionary of what?)  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: --When you say "each condition" is that subclass (as opposed to one Condition class, index a dictionary with its name, get its behavior function)? I can definitely create a protocol, but somewhere I still need to code this behavior into a function unique to each condition.

Comment: Just reread your solution. Hm, so one solution is not subclassing Condition 100 times, but breaking down the 100 different behaviors into commonalities, and write DoThisOnFlareUp(...) fewer times (like 30-50) leveraging the response of ChronicDisease, AcuteDisease, etc., so that Conditions that don't fall under some model just don't get a response from those composed objects?

Comment: Ok. . . sounds like you need the Observer pattern. You can have events (Sunny day, smoke, etc) different diseases can observe these events. Upon observing they can perform an action. . The objective-C equivalent of functors is 'blocks', though not 100% sure you need this. . Check out Key-value observing (lots of tutes) or maybe even ReactiveCocoa